# How to add permission for getting birthday from Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm unable to add permission for birthday, please help me out...
thanks in advance.

sample source code is :

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                // make request to the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                            // callback after Graph API response with user
                            // object
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                    Response response) {
                                if (user != null) {


                                }
                            }
                        });
            } 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

private static final List PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList(""user_birthday"");  //declaration

onClickPostStatusUpdate();// on button click call this function

private void onClickPostStatusUpdate() {

```
    performPublish(PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE);
```

}

private void performPublish(PendingAction action) {

```
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        pendingAction = action;
        if (hasPublishPermission()) {
            // We can do the action right away.
            handlePendingAction();
        } else {
            // We need to get new permissions, then complete the action when we get called back.
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_birthday","email"))
```

Comment: where do i add this??

Answer (score 0):

```
user.getBirthday();
```

I remeber using that and storing it as a string.